# Formula to copy a specific character from one cell to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using MS query to pull in data.  I need to create a column that copies the first character in another column.  For example:

```
Cell A1 -  E00633
Cell A2 -  B00842
Cell B1 -  I want this cell to read the first character "E" from cell A1
Cell B2 -  I want this cell to read the first character "B" from cell A2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You want the `LEFT` function. So in cell `B1`:

```
= LEFT(A1, 1)
```

Fill the formula down for the other cells.